# Shutdown a SynolgyNAS from an Raspberrypi over ssh script

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, shutdown, synology

I tried to shutdown my SynologyNAS after a backup over SSH in a script, but it doesn't work. Before it tries to shutdown the NAS it checks if the NAS is available.
This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export shutDown=false
while [ "$shutDown" = false ]
do
  if ! ping -c1 NAS-IP &>/dev/null; then
    echo "Ping Fail"
    shutDown=true
  else
    echo "Host Found"
    sshpass -p "NAS-Password" ssh -t root@NAS-IP 'shutdown -h now'
    sleep 1m
  fi
done
```

I want to shut it down because I only use it as a backup server. The Synology runs on a RAID with 2 HDDs so if one dies I just exchange it. With it doesn't work I mean it doesn't shut down the NAS

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "It' doesn't work" is hard to answer.

Comment: Why are you trying to shutdown a NAS? The best for a server is to run 365/year and stop as less as possible.

Comment: @kissu if the nas is in your house you might want to save electricity by turning it off when you are asleep (synology has [scheduling feature](https://kb.synology.com/en-global/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/system_hardware_schedule?version=6) to power off and back on automatically)

Comment: I'm into hardware. A NAS is something that is not eating a lot of your energy since it is optimized for specific tasks and usually do not have super heavy wattage. The other thing, is that each time you're turning your hardware off and on, it is actually shortening your hardware's life. To the point that an hardware can sometimes never boot again if you restart it one day but can run for several years if uninterrupted. Of course, some SSD is less prone to this kind of issue. So yeah, I would not recommend doing this. Maybe a standby mode but not switch your hardware on and off.

Comment: I want to shut it down because I only use it as a backup server. The Synology runs on a RAID with 2 HDDs so if one dies I just exchange it. With it doesn't work I mean it doesn't shut down the NAS